# React Native Microsoft Azure Auth

Tags: azure, react-native, authentication, mobile, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to test out the auth flow for a React Native(0.73.6) app. I'm using react-native-azure-auth (^1.8.9).

My signin function is firing, it is opening up a window to login.microsoftonline.com, but that is always just a blank white screen. I've attached some screenshots from my emulator.

Code:

```
import AzureAuth from 'react-native-azure-auth';

export const azureAuth = new AzureAuth({
  clientId: 'my client id',
  tenant: 'my tenant id',
});

export async function signIn() {
  try {
    let tokens = await azureAuth.webAuth.authorize({
      scope: 'openid profile User.Read Mail.Read',
    });
    console.log('tokens: ', tokens);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
*** This console log is firing when I close out the blank login.microsoftonline.com window.
error:
'aa.session.user_cancelled'
error_description:
'User cancelled the Auth'
    
  }
}
```

[image: Initial screen with sign in button]

[image: Popup after pressing sign in button]

[image: Blank window for signing in]

- Debug mode
- Followed documentation from react-native-azure-auth
- Expected a Microsoft login page to appear on the window
- Expected any error at all to see why nothing is appearing, but no errors, just a blank screen.

Comment: If possible, can you share your GitHub Repo here?

Comment: Check this [Github](https://github.com/vmurin/react-native-azure-auth?tab=readme-ov-file) Repo.

Comment: This code is not on Github... also, that is the package I'm using, I've already been to their repo.